# Getting a Data Dump from ADO.Net Then Formating it In a FlowDocument

Tags: c#, ado.net, flowdocument

I am Writing an app for a translation System, the translations i am getting are stored In the DB SQL hence the use of ADO. What i would like to Know is that is is possible to Speed up the Data that i am requesting from the DB.

At the Moment it takes 1min+ to get 10,000 values but when i made the mistake before of Dumping all the Translations in a Textbox it took under 10 sec. What i would like to know is it possible to get a big Dump of data then Format it into a FlowDocument Table ?

I honestly don't think the best way to do this is in a loop but it was the only way i got it to work and i would like to improve it.

My Current Code

```
        int counter = 1;
        int Value_00 = 1;
        string Value_01 = "";
        string Value_02 = "";


        bool bNextResult = true;

        while (bNextResult == true)
        {

            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                Value_00 = rdr.GetInt32(0);
                Value_01 = rdr.GetString(1);
                Value_02 = rdr.GetString(2);



                TableRow row = new TableRow();
                    trg1.Rows.Add(row);

                Paragraph pa = new Paragraph(new Run(Value_00.ToString()));
                TableCell cell = new TableCell(pa);
                    row.Cells.Add(cell);

                Paragraph pa1 = new Paragraph(new Run(Value_01));
                TableCell cell1 = new TableCell(pa1);
                    cell1.ColumnSpan = 4;
                cell1.Background = Brushes.DarkGray;
                    row.Cells.Add(cell1);

                Paragraph pa2 = new Paragraph(new Run(Value_02));
                TableCell cell2 = new TableCell(pa2);
                    cell2.ColumnSpan = 4;
                    row.Cells.Add(cell2);
                counter++;

                if (counter == 100) {

                break;
                }
            }
```

Comment: So it seems the overhead is in the construction of the document rather than the fetch speed from the database?  Considering a flow document can be represented as xaml then (depending your your unstated db) it may be possible to construct the whole thing there with a query.

Comment: So if i Understand i should Pass the Db information to a xaml file then make that xaml file get read and formatted by the FlowDocument, i will try this tomorrow and give an update on how it works Out. Thanks :)

Comment: I tried And cannot Fine a Guide On how to Change a XML Document to a FlowDocument Table i am now using (For XML Auto) Which makes my Query into an XML But no Clue as to format it into a FlowDocument Table.